# Change the default port number in systemjs

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am using the Angular.io default quickstart template to build a project.

When I give the command `npm start` it always show up the content of my project components in

> localhost:3000

Is their anyway to change the content to be visible on:

> localhost:8000

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be able to update `bs.config.json` to have the port configuration

```
{
  "port": 8000,
  "server": {
    ...
  }
}
```